# Modifying a property to automatically resolve "Cannot modify the return value" error

Tags: c#

I'd like to know if there's a built-in or an easy to implement way to handle this "Cannot modify the return value because it is not a variable" problem.

Let's say I have this class:

```
MyClass 
{ 
    Rectangle _rect = new Rectangle(1, 2, 3, 4);
    public Rectangle rect { get { return _rect; } set { _rect = value; } }
}
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
rect.Width += 20; // and this is where the error pops up
```

The usual approach would be to do this instead:

```
rect = new Rectangle(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width + 20, rect.Height);
```

But there has to be a way to automate it, right? And I don't mean just adding a bunch of properties to `MyClass` like `rect_width` and such (because I have 9 rectangles in my real class implementation, and that would be just bad), but something that would make this line of code work:

```
rect.Width += 20;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing really that you can do to circumvent the problem, since the Rectangle-class is immutable and that's the way it is intended to work.

However, you could expose a method that encapsulates the creation of new rectangles:

```
MyClass 
{ 
    Rectangle _rect;
    public Rectangle rect { get { return _rect; } set { _rect = value; } }

    public void AddWidth(int width)
    {
        rect = new Rectangle(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width + width, rect.Height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, just as I said in the question, it would be a bad move, because I really have 9 rectangles in my class implementation and there's no way to make a common method to reference `Rectangle`s since they're not reference types. I guess I could try extension methods then, but I've not succeeded in creating any one yet.

Comment: @Kenneth System.Drawing.Rectangle is a struct. The problem is not that it's immutable (it isn't), but that it is a value type and uses value semantics.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is something like `rect = rect.AddWidth (20)` e.g. using extension methods on `Rectangle`, unless you make `rect` a field or make `Rectangle` a (mutable) reference type. This is a core difference between value and reference types. It cannot be circumvented. Instead of looking for ways to circumvent it, you had better read up and understand it.

Sample extension method:

```
public static Rectangle AddWidth (this Rectangle r, double x)
{
    r.Width += x ;
    return r ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also define your own `MyRectangle` class to redefine the rectangle's properties like this:

```
public class MyRectangle
{
    private System.Drawing.Rectangle rect;

    public MyRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        this.rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public int X
    {
        get
        {
            return rect.X;
        }

        set
        {
            this.rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(value, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height);
        }
    }

    public int Y
    {
        get
        {
            return rect.Y;
        }

        set
        {
            this.rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(rect.X, value, rect.Width, rect.Height);
        }
    }

    public int Width
    {
        get
        {
            return rect.Width;
        }

        set
        {
            this.rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(rect.X, rect.Y, value, rect.Height);
        }
    }

    public int Height
    {
        get
        {
            return rect.Height;
        }

        set
        {
            this.rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, value);
        }
    }

    public System.Drawing.Rectangle Rectangle
    {
        get
        {
            return rect;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also redefind other properties to be wrappers to the internal Rectangle (like `Bottom`) or even some of the methods.  Or even make it `IComparable<Rectangle>`, you see the point...